# How can I input multiple values in one line?

Tags: python, input

How can I input multiple values in one line?
The output should look like a:8  b:5  c:6  d:4  e:0.1

I have tried this input:

`a, b, c, d, e = int(input(' '.format(a:, b:, c:, d:, e:)))`

but this didn't work.

Comment: Just do a,b,c,d=1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
a, b, c, d, e = input("Insert the 5 values: ").split()
print(f"a: {a}\nb: {b}\nc: {c}\nd: {d}\ne: {e}")
```

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Output:

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
d: 4
e: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want; the input numbers have to be entered with a comma in between:

```
a, b, c, d = (int(num) for num in input().split(','))
```

Explanation:

```
gotten_input = input('Enter a list of numbers separated by commas: ')
# user enters '1, 2, 3, 40, 500'
split_input_list = gotten_input.split(',')
# contains ['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 40', ' 500']
numbers_tuple = (int(num) for num in split_input_list)
# contains (1, 2, 3, 40, 500)
# now the tuple's values are ready to assign
a, b, c, d, e = numbers_tuple
# now a=1, b=2, c=3, d=40, e=500
```

However if a floating point number is entered, `int` won't do what you want; if you want a mix of `float`s and `int`s, your logic will have to get a little more complicated:

```
a, b, c, d, e = (float(num) if '.' in num else int(num) for num in input().split(','))
    # uses the Ternary operator to determine if the numbers should be converted to float or int
```

To have the exact output format you asked for, you can format the string how the other answer had, other than without newlines:

```
print(f"a:{a} b:{b} c:{c} d:{d} e:{e}")
```

Or:

```
print("a:{} b:{} c:{} d:{} e:{}".format(*(int(num) for num in input().split(','))))
# The * unpacks the tuple into a list of arguments to send to format()
```

Comment: I tried but the output doesn't look like for exp. a:8 b:5 c:6 d:4 e:0.1. I just got like 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: a,b,c,d=[int(x) for x in input("please enter value ").split(" ")]
print(a,b,c,d)