# Input 3 number in one line

Tags: python, input

We can get 3 number from user like this

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
```

Now how can we get 3 number from user in one line?

```
a , b , c = int(input())
```

I tried this but it's not ok

Comment: `a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())` – but there's really no point in doing that. You should avoid trying to fit things into a single line “just because”.

Comment: get the input string, `.split()` it by whatever separator is between the numbers (space, comma?), and convert each of the split parts into a number separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
a , b , c = map(int,(input().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```py
a, b, c = input("Insert the 3 values: ").split()
print(f"a: {a}\nb: {b}\nc: {c}")
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706367/how-can-i-input-multiple-values-in-one-line) similar question for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading data from a `.txt` file and you're wanting to map variables a, b, and c in one line.

Example:

```py
inputFile = open("example.txt",r)

a, b = map(int, inputFile.readline().split())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try:
    a,b,c  = map(int,input('input').split())

    print(a,b,c)
    
except:
    print('input is no good')
```